# gulp-sass compiling bass scss file, but not partials

Tags: sass, gulp, partial, node-sass

I'm new to Sass, so sorry if this is basic.

I'm compiling my main sass file using gulp, which works fine. However, I'm having trouble bringing in partials - I'm doing it wrong, but I can't figure out how.

**style.scss**

```css
@import partial

$main-color: rgb(117, 0, 0);

h1 {
   color: $main-color;
}

h2 {
   color: $secondary-color;
}
```

**_partial.scss**

```css
$secondary-color: rgb(175, 87, 205);
```

**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('default', function() {
   return gulp.src('style.scss')
      .pipe(sass(
         {outputStyle: 'compressed'})
         .on('error', sass.logError)
      )
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
})
```

Do I need to add something to the gulp task to make it compile both the base scss file and the partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 1 of your `style.scss` should be `@import 'partial';`

Sass requires the quotes and the semicolon (for the semicolon you may have been tripped up by the fact that `.sass` Sass wouldn't use that semicolon)

Comment: That's true - thanks. I also discovered that I had omitted the string quotes on the filename. So it should be `@import 'partial'`. Add this to your answer and I'll accept it :)